# Join lists into one according to index

Tags: python, list

I have lists and want to join into one, according to index position. For example:

```
A = ['a','b','c']
B = [1,2,3]
C = ['10','20','30']
```

Wanted output `list = [['a', 1, '10'],['b', 2, '20'],['c', 3, '30']]`

My code gives me error `TypeError: list.append() takes exactly one argument (3 given)`

```
list=[]
for i in range(len(A)):
    list.append([A[i],B[i],C[i]])
```

Note: `map` and `zip` functions are not allowed.

Comment: Your code is correct, But please don't use the [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) as variables. list one of them

Comment: The given code does not give that error, instead it produces the required output.

Comment: I'm guessing the actual code is `lst.append(A[i], B[i], C[i])`? without warping the values in a list?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code seems correct, but if the error is still there, what you can try is: instead of `list.append([A[i],B[i],C[i]])`, replace to `list.append(([A[i],B[i],C[i]]))`. I believe it's going to work.

EDIT

Technically speaking, there is no problem using `list` as a variable name, that is, your code is going to work with it. But it's not advisable to use it.

Comment: Why would changing the appended value type from a list to a tuple will make any difference?

Comment: As I said: his code seems correct, that is, it makes no difference. But, if the errors keeps coming, he may try another approach, so he can see if this new approach gives him the desired answer.